# Two-Button Menu Iteration

Tags: python, micropython

I've got a script that I'm adapting to micropython on a 2040, and I want to use two buttons to navigate the menu structure. I can't figure out how to make the iterate loop in the multi-choice menus work right... here's what I've got so far:

```
""" fit: a productivity logger """
import time
import sys
import os
import uhashlib
import machine

def final_print(sec,final_hash,final_survey):
    """ leaves the summary on the screen before shutting down """
    mins = sec // 60
    sec = sec % 60
    hours = mins // 60
    mins = mins % 60
    short_sec = int(sec)
    duration = (str(hours) + "/" + str(mins) + "/" + str(short_sec))
    print("> fit the",str(final_hash)," went ",str(final_survey)," lasted //",str(duration))

def timer_down(f_seconds,timer_focus):
    """ counts down for defined period """
    now = time.time()
    end = now + f_seconds
    while now < end:
        now = time.time()
        fit_progress(now,end,timer_focus,f_seconds)
        b1pressed = button1.value()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if not b1pressed:
             print('Ended Manually!')
             break

def timer_up(timer_focus):
    """ counts up for indefinite period """
    now = time.time()
    while True:
         minutes = int((time.time() - now) / 60)
         print(str(timer_focus)," for ",str(minutes))
         b1pressed = button1.value()
         time.sleep(0.01)
         if not b1pressed:
             print('Ended Manually!')
             break

def fit_progress(now,end,timer_focus,f_seconds):
    """ tracks progress of a count-down fit and prints to screen """
    remain = end - now
    f_minutes = int((remain)/60)
    j = 1 - (remain / f_seconds)
    pct = int(100*j)
    print(str(timer_focus),str(f_minutes),str(pct))

def multi_choice(options):
    done = 0
    while done == 0:
        for i in options:
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            time.sleep(.01)
            b1released = button1.value()
            b2released = button2.value()
            if b2pressed and not b1pressed:
                print(i," b2 pressed")
                continue
            if b1pressed and not b2pressed:
                print(i," b1 pressed")
                time.sleep(2)
                return i

button1 = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = machine.Pin(3, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

print("format?")
fType = multi_choice(['30-minute fit','60-minute fit','indefinite fit'])
print(fType," selected")

print("focus?")
F_FOCUS = multi_choice(['personal fit','work fit','learn fit','admin fit'])
print(F_FOCUS," selected")

fStart = time.time()

if fType == "30-minute fit":
    timer_down(1800,F_FOCUS)
elif fType == "60-minute fit":
    timer_down(3600,F_FOCUS)
elif fType == "indefinite fit":
    timer_up(F_FOCUS)
else:
    sys.exit()

fEnd = time.time()

print("sentiment?")
F_SURVEY = multi_choice(['+','=','-'])
print(F_SURVEY," selected")

fDuration = fEnd - fStart

F_HASH = uhashlib.sha256(str(fEnd).encode('utf-8')).digest()
F_HASH_SHORT = F_HASH[0:3]

fitdb = open("data.csv","a")
fitdb.write(str(F_HASH)+","+str(fType)+","+str(F_FOCUS)+","+str(F_SURVEY)+","+str(fStart)+","+str(fEnd)+","+str(fDuration)+"\n")
fitdb.close()

final_print(fDuration,F_HASH_SHORT,F_SURVEY)
print(F_HASH_SHORT," ",F_HASH)
```

In particular, this is the logic I'm wrangling with:

```
def multi_choice(options):
    done = 0
    while done == 0:
        for i in options:
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            time.sleep(.01)
            b1released = button1.value()
            b2released = button2.value()
            if b2pressed and not b1pressed:
                print(i," b2 pressed")
                continue
            if b1pressed and not b2pressed:
                print(i," b1 pressed")
                time.sleep(2)
                return i
```

Here's what I'm wanting to do:

For each item in the set,

- Display the item, wait for button press
- If button 1 is pressed, select that item, return the item.
- If button 2 is pressed, display the next item, wait for button press.
- (iterate until button 1 pressed to select item)

Again, this is micropython, so I don't have all the modules you'd think available... woudl be best to do this in raw code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.01 second is way too short.  The key is, after you detect "button down", you need to wait for "button up".  You need something like:

```
def wait_for_btn_up(btn):
    count = 2
    while count > 0:
        if btn.value();
            count = 2
        else:
            count -= 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

    
def multi_choice(options):
    for i in options:
        print( "trying", i )
        # Wait for any button press.
        while 1:
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            if b1pressed or b2pressed: 
                break
        if b1pressed:
            print( i, "chosen" )
            wait_for_btn_up(button1)
            return i
        # We know B2 was pressed.
        wait_for_btn_up(button2)
```

Comment: This was really helpful logically, but it doesn't quite work for this application, since the GPIO buttons in MicroPython on the 2040 need to be read frequently... that's why I needed the crazy 0.01s refresh in the last one. Of course, that messes with the selection loop then, which is what I was wrangling with. Your version is logically great for the two-button part, but now the button states are really sporadically read.

Comment: I've done a LOT of embedded coding, and your comment about "need to be read frequently" doesn't make sense to me.  Now, maybe you need to implement some debounce logic; lots of small systems don't have that built-in.  That just means calling a function to wait for key up to be stable.  I can tweak the answer to do that.

Comment: Not questioning your skill, for sure, the logic is sound and way better than the mess I had, but I don't think this is a debounce issue. It seems the method I'm using to collect button presses needs further refinement. Using your function, I can only press either button (1, 2) once before it stops responding, and I have to press the other one... at which point that stops responding and I have to press the other one, an alternating-button input. It's strange.

Comment: Well, then, perhaps I don't understand your spec.  If B1 and B2 are independent, momentary, normally-open buttons, then the code should work.

Comment: They are, it's just two Cherry MX switches, simple, independent, normally-open. One is on GPIO pin2 ("button1"), the other on GPIO pin3 ("button2"). With the above, I can only alternate the pressing of button1 and button2 to any effect. Pressing either button twice in a row is without effect the second time (which precludes the actual selection half the time, and scrolling through options more than one deep). button1.value() = "1" when circuit is open, and button1.value() = "0" when circuit is closed, but it's almost like the logic isn't re-checking the value after it changes.

Comment: You can see what I am trying to do, right?  I'm trying for edge detection, not just level detection.  Once `multi_choice` returns, the current state shouldn't matter.